# R Shiny Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to get some inject custom javascript into my shiny app. I am able to get the page to load and run the javascript, but cannot get the data back from the javascript into shiny for processing by pressing the 'confirm_list' button.  I have been following this tutorial (https://www.aridhia.com/blog/the-sky-is-not-the-limit-embedding-raw-html-and-javascript-to-create-dynamic-ui-elements-in-shiny-applications/).

The folder structure of the three files is

```
|-ui.r
|-server.r
|-widget.r
|-www
     |-script.js
```

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(stringi)

source("../widgets.R")

attendeeForm <- stri_replace_all_charclass(attendeeForm, "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}", " ")

# Define UI space for our application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # First lets create a button which will trigger adding a new attendee form.
  actionButton('add_Button', 'Add attendee!'),

  # Now, lets create a DIV element to which we will be adding attendee forms.
  div(id="div"),

  tags$head(HTML(sprintf(
    "<script>
    function addAttendee() {
      var attendee = \'%s\';
      $('#div').append(attendee)
    }
  </script>", attendeeForm))),

  tags$body(HTML('<script>
addAttendee();
    </script>')),

  # On click event to triger addAttendee function
  tags$head(HTML("
  <script>
    $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) { 
      $('#add_Button').on('click', function() {addAttendee()})
    })
  </script>
")),

  # Trigger removeAttendee function when button of class 'remover' is clicked.
  tags$head(HTML("
  <script>
    function removeAttendee(el) {
      $(el).parents(\"p\").remove()  
    };

    $(document).on('click','.remover',function() {
      removeAttendee(this)
    });   
  </script>
")),

  actionButton('confirm_list', 'Confirm attendees'),

  tags$head(HTML("
  <script>
    $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) { 

      $('#confirm_list').on('click', function() {getAttendees()})

    });               
  </script>
")),

  tags$head(tags$script(src = 'script.js')),

  tableOutput('attendee_table')

))
```

server.R

```
# Define server logic
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Server code goes here

  output$attendee_table <- renderTable({
    df <- data.frame(Name = unlist(input$attendees$name),
                     Department = unlist(input$attendees$department),
                     Email = unlist(input$attendees$email))
    df  
  })
})
```

widgets.R

```
# Creating raw HTML widget form containing ("Name","Department","Email") fields and Remove button of CSS class 'remover'

attendeeForm <- '<p>

                     <label for="name">Name: </label>
                     <input style="width: 150px;" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name">

                     <!--Department field-->
                     <label for="department">Department: </label>
                     <input style="width: 150px;" id="department" type="text" placeholder="Enter department">

                     <!--Email field-->
                     <label for="email">Email: </label>
                     <input style="width: 150px;" id="email" type="text" placeholder="example@email.com">

                     <!--Remove button-->
                     <input type = "button" class="remover" value = &#10008>
                     </p>
                     '
```

script.js

```
function getAttendees() {
  var name = [];
  var department = [];
  var email = [];
  var attendees = [];

  $(".name").each(function() {
    name.push($(this).val())
  })

  $(".department").each(function() {
    department.push($(this).val())
  })

  $(".email").each(function() {
    email.push($(this).val())
  }) 

  Shiny.onInputChange("attendees", {name, department, email})
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using square brackets instead of curly in the Shiny.onInputChange command

Comment: in javascript you should not escape single quote use var attendee = '%s'; also if string have newline it can't be in javascript string unless you use string with backticks (es6 feature)

Comment: @jcubic, that section of the code works. I have to escape that otherwise R will treat it incorrectly.

Comment: @Bertil Nestorius - that did not appear to do anything

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the widget and script combination. In the script I was trying to reference the classes name, department and email, but in the widgets.R where I built the html I used id instead of class.

Therefore widgets.r becomes

```
attendeeForm <- '<p>

                     <label for="name">Name: </label>
                     <input style="width: 150px;" class="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name">

                     <!--Department field-->
                     <label for="department">Department: </label>
                     <input style="width: 150px;" class="department" type="text" placeholder="Enter department">

                     <!--Email field-->
                     <label for="email">Email: </label>
                     <input style="width: 150px;" class="email" type="text" placeholder="example@email.com">

                     <!--Remove button-->
                     <input type = "button" class="remover" value = &#10008>
                     </p>
                     '
```